HTML/CSS Does not show videobackground for mobile
I have this code that shows a video on mobile. It just shows a play button without the video behind it. When I press on play the video starts normally but I want something behind it.
This is what it looks like:

<div class="flex justify-center sm:mt-[-200px] z-10 relative lg:flex-row pb-12 xl:pb-12 flex-col-reverse items-center bg-gradient-to-l from-yellow-50 to-yellow-100 rounded-xl">
  <div class="video-container mt-14 rounded-lg overflow-hidden w-full max-w-[800px]">
    <!-- Heading before the video -->
    <div class="text-center text-4xl font-bold mb-10">
      Learn about
    </div>

    <!-- Video container -->
    <div class="w-[90%] mx-auto">
      <!-- Encapsulate video within a div for better control -->
      <video class="w-full h-auto rounded-lg>
          <source src=" {{ url_for( 'static', filename='home.mp4' ) }} " type="video/mp4 ">
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
  </div>
</div>
</div>


You can add a poster image into the video tag to display an image before the video starts, <video poster="/images/example.jpg">

Use autoplay, loop, muted attributes in <video> tag.
<video class="w-full h-auto rounded-lg autoplay loop muted>
  <source src="{{ url_for('static', filename='home.mp4') }}" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>


autoplay - Will automatically play the video
loop - video will never end it'll run on a loop
muted - video will be running without any sound (best for background)

